# Delete " from a file content

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-v3.0

I am querying list of domain joined computers using powershell as below:

```
dsquery.exe computer > "C:\testfolder\host.txt"
```

Output is working as expected, but it is as shown below:

```
"CN=WIN-20CCF3DC8D,OU=Domain Controllers,DC=hosting,DC=xyz,DC=com"
"CN=WIN-20XYS8CM7D,OU=Computers,DC=hosting,DC=xyz,DC=com"
```

Here I need the following to do.

**Either:**

I need to edit this file (using powershell): remove all **"** character, remove all entries where OU not equal to Computers.

**Or**

I need to get contents of CN to a string but without **"**.

Have tried using

```
$contents = Get-Content C:\testfolder\host.txt | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ""}
```

but not seems to be working. Can someone please help me on this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$contents = Get-Content C:\testfolder\host.txt | where { $_ -match "OU=Computers" } | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ""}
```

Then `echo $contents` gives :

```
CN=WIN-20XYS8CM7D,OU=Computers,DC=hosting,DC=xyz,DC=com
```

---

This returns only lines containing `OU=Computers` and removes double quotes from those lines.

Comment: or you can use this too... (for removing ")

Get-Content C:\testfolder\temp_host.txt | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '"', ''} | sc C:\testfolder\host.txt